# Question about the "Legendary" Badge

Tags: support, badges

When I was looking at the badges I started reading the Legendary Badge and noticed that it says:

> Hit the daily reputation cap on 150 days

Now, I interpreted this as: "On the 150th day you have been here, if you get the daily reputation cap, you will earn this badge". Now, my first reaction was like "Wth?" because the Epic badge says "Hit the daily reputation cap on 50 days" and if you interpret it the way I did for the Legendary badge, you would probably think "Why is Epic only Silver and why is Legendary Gold?" Maybe it's just me, but, if I understand what you guys really mean wouldn't:

> Hit the daily reputation cap for 150 days in a row

be better. Or am I completely misunderstanding this?

Comment: To interpret it as you do, I guess it would really have to say "Hit the daily reputation cap on the 150th day you have been here." The description says "days", plural.

Comment: @MPelletier: Either way it could be phrased better.

Comment: @thyrgle, for sure.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, to get this badge you have to hit the daily rep cap on 150 days. The days are not consecutive; it should probably just say something like

"Hit the daily rep cap on 150 occasions"

This same logic also applies to the epic badge.